# User Details Don't Show Up Using Pagination

Tags: c#, winforms, list, linq

I've to show user details in **DataGridView** with pagination and almost done working with it. The problem is when I use **skip** and **Take** in `LINQ`, it doesn't show any data but without it works as follows:

```
grdUserDetails.DataSource = aUserDetail; //shows list of user details
grdUserDetails.DataSource = aUserDetail.Skip(startRow).Take(pageSize); //Doesn't show anything
```

This is the code that I've tried so far:

```
public int pageSize = 1;
public Users()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindDataGridView(1);
}

private void BindDataGridView(int pageIndex)
{
   List<UserDetails> aUserDetail = null;

   aUserDetail = GetUserDetails();

   totalRecordCount = aUserDetail.Count;
   int startRow = pageIndex * pageSize;

   grdUserDetails.DataSource = aUserDetail.Skip(startRow).Take(pageSize); //Here is the main issue that I am stuck with
   BindPager(totalRecordCount, pageIndex);
}

private void BindPager(int recordCount, int currentPage)
{
   double getPageCount = (double)((decimal)totalRecordCount / (decimal)pageSize);
   int pageCount = (int)Math.Ceiling(getPageCount);

   List<ListItem> lstItem = new List<ListItem>();

   if (currentPage > 1)
   {
      lstItem.Add(new ListItem { Text = "First", Value = "1" });
   }

   if (currentPage > 1)
   {
      lstItem.Add(new ListItem { Text = "<<", Value = (currentPage - 1).ToString() });
   }

   for (int i = 1; i <= recordCount; i++)
   {
      lstItem.Add(new ListItem { Text = i.ToString(), Value = i.ToString(), Selected = i == currentPage });
   }

   if (currentPage < pageCount)
   {
      lstItem.Add(new ListItem { Text = ">>", Value = (currentPage + 1).ToString() });
   }

   if (currentPage != pageCount)
   {
       lstItem.Add(new ListItem { Text = "Last", Value = pageCount.ToString() });
   }

   plPager.Controls.Clear();

   int count = 0;
   foreach (ListItem lst in lstItem)
   {
      Button btnPage = new Button();
      btnPage.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(38 * count, 6);
      btnPage.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(36, 20);

      btnPage.Name = lst.Value;
      btnPage.Text = lst.Text;

      btnPage.Enabled = !lst.Selected;
      btnPage.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.ListItem_Click);

      plPager.Controls.Add(btnPage);
      count++;
   }
}

private void ListItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Button btnPager = (sender as Button);
   this.BindDataGridView(int.Parse(btnPager.Name));
}
```

I've used two classes for the **WinForm** project. One is the **UserDetails** and another is **Page** to bind controls dynamically with a **Panel**:

```
public class ListItem
{
   public string Text { get; set; }
   public string Value { get; set; }
   public bool Selected { get; set; }
}

public class UserDetails
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

public List<UserDetails> GetUserDetails()
{
  List<UserDetails> lst = new List<UserDetails>
  {
     new UserDetails { Id = 1001, Name = "John" },
     new UserDetails { Id = 1001, Name = "Jack" } 
  };

  return lst;
}
```

Finally in the form, I've **DataGridView** named `grdUserDetails` and a panel `plPager` to show user details and the pagination. I am hoping, it would be a silly mistake and missed something doing so.

Comment: Have you tried debugging and does it get value there?

Comment: Yes @AT-2017. I've already checked that and it has the records but doesn't show up in the **DataGridView**.

Comment: Do you start your page index at 0?

Comment: Why have two `if (currentPage > 1)` blocks back to back?  BTW, `plPager.Controls.Clear();` does not dispose of the existing controls that are being cleared.  You have to explicitly dispose of them.

Comment: @David Lee, no - I've started with pageIndex 1 and with 0, it's the same.

Comment: @LarsTech I am still struggling with it and trying to make it better. Never mind - I didn't get the **dispose** section. Basically with this **plPager.Controls.Clear();**, I am making it free or dispose for the next page iteration. Do I've to make any changes here actually?

Comment: Does hard coding in a startRow of 0 and a pageSize of >1 still produce null? `grdUserDetails.DataSource = aUserDetail.Skip(0).Take(15);`

Comment: I've tried your code but as you have written, it displays nothing n the `DataGridView`. @David Lee even hard-coding will not work. May be the issue is another for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things.

1) startRow needs to be less by one because of zero-based indexing.

2) Your LINQ needs to be converted to a List<>.

So, try it this way:

```
grdUserDetails.DataSource = aUserDetail.Skip(startRow - 1).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @LarsTech and worked as expected. I really didn't think of it and need to pay more attention.